# How to autofocus ngx-mat-intl-tel-input search box instead of input field?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular9

I am using NgxMatIntlTelInput library and I have created component like this:

```
<ngx-mat-intl-tel-input
   [enablePlaceholder]="true"
   [enableSearch]="true"
   placeholder="Telephone"
   name="phone">
</ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
```

At the moment when user clicks on this field, the cursor / focus will go to the input field.
But I would like to autofocus Search box instead.

Any idea how to do that?

EDIT:
Added [example](https://ngx-mat-intl-tel-input-demo-5grvbs.stackblitz.io).

Comment: It would be easier to have a look at the problem if you provided a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
You can set one up over at [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: Sure thing, boss. Added one